# Going to newline pulls existing code to beginning of line

Tags: indentation

I'm not that experienced with vim. I've been working with some html/php in macvim and there's this annoying behaviour that I don't know how to control. See below. `x` denotes the current position of the cursor

```
 <?php
    $relatedPrograms = get_field('related_programs');

    echo '<ul class="min-list">';
    foreach($relatedPrograms as $program) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($program); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($program); ?></a></li>

    <?php }x
    ?>  
    </div>
```

I want to create a blank line between `?php }` and `?>` but I don't want anything to get pulled to the beginning of the line. After pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it pulls the whole content to the beginning of the current line and enters newline. `x` denotes the new position of the cursor:

```
    echo '<ul class="min-list">';
       foreach($relatedPrograms as $program) { ?>
           <li><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($program); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($program); ?></a></li>

<?php }  // this line has been pulled to the beginning of line.
x 
       ?>  
       </div>
```

My vimrc

```
set nocompatible
syntax on
set nowrap
set encoding=utf8

" Tabs vs Space {{{
set tabstop=4                           " Use 4 spaces for <Tab> and :retab
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab                           " Expand tabs to spaces
set smarttab
" }}}

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'junegunn/vim-easy-align'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plug 'tomtom/tcomment_vim'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'

call plug#end()

" Start Nerdtree if no file is specified
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif

" start NERDTree Ctrl-n
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" Leader C is the prefix for code related mappings
" comment/uncomment line with ,cc
noremap <silent> <Leader>cc :TComment<CR>
" Sytastic config
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#                                   "syntastic
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}                    "syntastic
set statusline+=%*                                              "syntastic

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1                    "syntastic
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1                               "syntastic
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1                               "syntastic
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0                                 "syntastic

" Mappings to access buffers (don't use "\p" because a
" delay before pressing "p" would accidentally paste).
" \l       : list buffers
" \b \f \g : go back/forward/last-used
" \1 \2 \3 : go to buffer 1/2/3 etc
nnoremap <Leader>l :ls<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b :bp<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>f :bn<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>g :e#<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>1 :1b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>2 :2b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>3 :3b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>4 :4b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>5 :5b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>6 :6b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>7 :7b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>8 :8b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>9 :9b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>0 :10b<CR>
" It's useful to show the buffer number in the status line.
set laststatus=2 statusline=%02n:%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

Comment: If i had to bet, id guess you should look into that auto-aline plugin, or check if any autoindent-like settings got turned on

Comment: Thanks - how would I do that?

Comment: One idea is to reduce your vimrc to a bare minimum (make a backup!!), say, set nocompatible, and see if you still have the problem. Its just like debugging code; debug your vimrc and if you’re still having problems edit the question with what you tried

Comment: Ok. Thanks - it's vim-easy-align that was causing it.

Comment: You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by David, I experimented with .vimrc to see what's the culprit by stripping it down to bare minimum.
It turned out the offending plugin was 'vim-easy-align'

Thank you.